# Why can't Django-rest-swagger find my api paths?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, swagger

I've installed Django-Rest-Swagger and done what I can to set it up. From looking at the docs, I don't really understand if I need to do any more to make it work.

If I go to `localhost:800/docs` I see this:

[image: swagger just sits looking for resources]

If I navigate to that URL, I see this JSON:

[image: The Json at localhost:8000/docs/api-docs with my three api paths]

So if those exist, what would stop it from finding them?

I don't think it's that I have a [model serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24330885/1075247) I don't see why that would be. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25803206/1075247), but I don't think that's it either.

---

Swagger settings:

```
SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    'exclude_namespaces': [],
    'api_version': '0.1',
    'api_path': '/characters/api',
    'enabled_methods': [
        'get',
        'post',
        'put',
        'patch',
        'delete'
    ],
    'api_key': '',
    'is_authenticated': False,
    'is_superuser': False,
    'permission_denied_handler': None,
    'info': {
        'contact': 'froo@barr.com',
        'description': 'This is a nWoD-DB Api thing',
        'license': 'No Licence',
        'licenseUrl': '',
        'termsOfServiceUrl': '',
        'title': 'nWoD-DB',
    },
    'doc_expansion': 'none',
}
```

Urls.py

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # Examples:
                       # url(r'^$', 'nwod_characters.views.home', name='home'),
                       # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                       url(r'^characters/', include('characters.urls')),
                       url(r'^djangular/', include('djangular.urls')),
                       url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                                                  namespace='rest_framework')),
                       url(r'^docs/',
                           include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
                       )
#characters/urls.py
mage_list = MageViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})

mage_detail = MageViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})
user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list'
})
user_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve'
})


urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^api/root$', api_root),
    url(r'^api/mages$', mage_list, name='mage-list'),
    url(r'^api/mages/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', mage_detail, name='mage-detail'),
    url(r'^api/users$', user_list, name='user-list'),
    url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', user_detail, name='user-detail'),
])
urlpatterns += [url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'), ]
```

Comment: Could you post your settings and urls, please ?

Comment: @AdelaN is that any better?

Comment: Is the swagger-ui part of your application or do you run it separately?

Comment: @Ron I think it's bundled in with the django-rest-swagger package?

Comment: Right you are. Try opening the URLs you see in the `localhost:800/docs` response. For example, `localhost:800/docs/characters/api/mages`. If they are all accessible, and you can, please share them here as they may have an error in them.

Comment: Another option is to check your browser's console for errors, that may help pin-pointing the problem.

Comment: @Ron I like the way you think.  Will try to do so from home

Answer (score 2):

The 'problem' is that you are doing "include('characters.urls')" as far as I can find, rest_framework_swagger has a hard time finding any urls that aren't explicitly in your root urlpatterns - if you want to guarantee that swagger will find them you'll have to expand them into your urlpatterns instead of including them from another file, i.e.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'nwod_characters.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^api/root$', api_root),
        url(r'^api/mages$', mage_list, name='mage-list'),
        url(r'^api/mages/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', mage_detail, name='mage-detail'),
        url(r'^api/users$', user_list, name='user-list'),
        url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', user_detail, name='user-detail'),
....
```

I'd be happy to know if anyone has a way to configure swagger to avoid having to lump all of the urls.